# "Obrigado" vs "obrigada"

Tags: concordância, gênero, concordância-nominal

Quando agradecemos a alguém (obrigado/obrigada ou agradecido/agradecida), como escolhemos a palavra a usar?

Relativamente ao nosso género ou ao género do receptor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

É referente ao nosso gênero, pois somos nós quem estamos agradecidos, ou obrigados em relação ao receptor.

Ao falar *Obrigado(a)*, imagine-se dizendo o mesmo que *Me sinto obrigado(a) a retribuí-lo(a)*. Neste desmembramento, conseguimos ver com mais clareza que o *obrigado(a)* depende do gênero de quem está falando, ao passo que o *retribuí-lo(a)* depende do gênero do receptor.

Portanto, utilizar o termo *obrigado* com o gênero do receptor não faria sentido.

Comment: Lembrando que se você estiver em um grupo de pessoas e quiser responder em nome do grupo todo vc também pode dizer *obrigados(as)*.

Comment: @gabrieloshiro, em pt-br isso NUNCA é observado.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy "pode dizer"

Comment: @GabrielOshiro de notar que em PT-PT, tal como em PT-BR, nunca e observado o "obrigados".

Comment: @Omni "pode dizer"

Comment: Nunca ouvi obrigados

Comment: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/obrigadoa-e-obrigadosas/10643