# Can "obrigado" be used by women?

Tags: diferenças, gendered-speech

When first learning Portuguese we (all?) learn that *obrigado* is for men and *obrigada* for women.

But then I often hear women say *obrigad**o***, too! (And I've made sure I didn't mishear.) What's going on here? Can women use *obrigado*? Is *obrigada* particularly "feminine"? Is *obrigado* when said by a woman more like "Thanks!" or "Cheers!" (as opposed to *obrigada* being "Thank you!")?

Comment: I'm surprised to see information in these answers not covered in another question: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/31/84

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both forms are accepted in current use, by women, at least in Brazil. *Obrigada* is in fact the feminine form of the verb "obrigar" and stresses the gender of the speaker. I believe (unsupported by research) that this is by far the most common alternative.

*Obrigado* is the masculine form of the verb, but its use in this situation can be understood as an evolution towards a gender-neutral iconic response, much like an interjection (and I wouldn't dare trying to explain why this has happened). This evolution may be frowned upon by stern grammarians, but in language use is king, so time will tell what is going to happen.

Comment: Do you have sources for that explanation?

Comment: This means that both forms are grammatically correct?

Comment: The sources I would be able to find are grammatical, and are mostly based on the normative thinking that is so prevalent in our ordinary understanding of language. In this particular case, there is no discussion: both forms are considered grammatical, both in usage and in norm. Sadly, it is quite hard for me to find sources from *linguistic* research to support my answer. Any help will be very welcome, in this regard.

Comment: ficou-lhe obrigada/obrigado https://veja.abril.com.br/coluna/sobre-palavras/por-que-dizemos-obrigado-quando-agradecemos/

Answer (score 5):

Em Portugal ouve-se mulheres dizer *obrigado*, homens dizer *obrigada* ou *obrigadinha*, e ainda, raramente, pessoas de ambos os sexos dizer *obrigados* quando se dirigem a várias pessoas. Mas isto ouve-se especialmente a pessoas menos educadas e cada vez menos frequentemente.

O que faz sentido gramaticalmente é a mulher dizer *obrigada* e o homem *obrigado*. A pessoa fica com uma obrigação junto de quem lhe fez um favor, logo uma mulher fica obrigada, um homem fica obrigado.

Eu penso que as pessoas estão pouco ou nada conscientes deste sentido da palavra quando dizem ou ouvem obrigado/a. Indício disso é ouvirmos, raramente, aqui em Portugal, coisas como, "Muito obrigado, Sr. José, pela sua ajuda." Responde o Sr. José, "Obrigado, não! Ajudei de livre vontade." É difícil saber se isto é dito só humoristicamente, ou se o Sr. José não sabe realmente quem é que está ali obrigado.

Nunca ouvi trocas nos agradecimentos alternativos e menos comuns *muito agradecido/a* ou *muito grato/a*. Nestes casos, por vezes, ouve-se a frase completa, *fico-lhe muito agradecido*, ou *estou-lhe muito grata*.

Comment: Gostei da sua sua resposta embora não esclareça o facto de ser correto ou não as mulheres usarem *obrigado*.

Comment: Gosto sempre de analisar, mas nem sempre de ditar lei. Cada mulher que decida por si mesma.

Answer (score 4):

Em ptBR "obrigado" é uma forma estereotipada de agradecimento que, quando usado isoladamente, como uma interjeição, significa "estou agradecido" ou "agradeço". **Sendo uma interjeição, não varia em gênero e número.** e pode ser usado tanto por homem(ns) quanto por mulher(es).

Contudo, a maioria dos gramáticos considera esse uso de "obrigado" uma forma adjetival e, **como adjetivo, tem que concordar com o sujeito em gênero e número.**

- obrigado
- obrigada
- estamos obrigados
- estamos obrigadas

Concluindo então, todas as formas são aceitas. A única forma errada é uso do feminino por homens, uma vez que nesse caso não se pode dizer que foi o uso de uma interjeição.

Hoje em dia poucas pessoas dizem "obrigado" no sentido de que sentem-se devedores por terem sido objeto de um favor ou atenção. Significa apenas "estou agradecido/a".

fonte: ["obrigado ou obrigada?"](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1008)

Comment: *são aceitas* quer dizer que é correto? Ou apenas que se usa no dia a dia? É que são duas coisas distintas.

Comment: @JorgeB.  São aceitas como formas corretas.

Answer (score 0):

A língua portuguesa distingue na sua linguística o feminino e o masculino não havendo indiferente.
Neste caso a mulher diz obrigada e o homem obrigado. A palavra define uma gratidão e por isso sempre que alguém diz obrigada/o recebe de volta a resposta: De nada, agradecida/o ou grata/grato.

O português do Brasil apesar de seguir as mesmas regras linguísticas não é falado da mesma maneira que o português de Portugal e é aí que as dúvidas surgem.

Comment: Isto importa menos ou nem importa: o que queres dizer por «regra lingüística»?